# How do can I use the setvalue() in a foreach() loop?[Google sheet Script]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

It's my first post and I am a newbee in google sheets script programing.

I want to my script when I run it, to go first through a list of clients(row[0]). when the client has been found, test for the row[2] if it is a "yes" or "no" string object and when it is a "yes" option, rewrite it as a "no".

another question that i have is how can I know which ligne (row) i am testing when i am using the foreach function.

```
function cleanpassagepage(NomClient)
{
  const passageclientsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("relevé chez client");
  const numlastrowIS = passageclientsheet.getLastRow();
  const dataIS = passageclientsheet.getRange(2,1,numlastrowIS,3).getValues();
  dataIS.forEach(function(row)
  {
    if (row[0]==NomClient)
    {
      if(row[2]=="non")
      {
        row[2]= setValue("oui");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

PS : the script doesn't give me an error to understand where did I messed up.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you call this function only once the use of setValue() is okay.  If you are calling this many times you should investigate using setValues() instead.

```
function cleanpassagepage(NomClient) {
  const passageclientsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("relevé chez client");
  const numlastrowIS = passageclientsheet.getLastRow();
  const dataIS = passageclientsheet.getRange(2,1,numlastrowIS,3).getValues();
  var i = 0;
  for( i=0; i<dataIS.length; i++ ) {
    if( dataIS[i][0] === NomClient ) {
      if( dataIS[i][2] === "non" ) {
        passageclientsheet.getRange(i+1,3).setValue("oui");
      }
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it and it did not work, maybe it has somthing to do with the fact that I have to go through every ligne in the sheet

Answer (score 0):

setValue is for range

you can try this (I have also added the num of row)

```
function cleanpassagepage(NomClient)
{
  const passageclientsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("relevé chez client");
  const numlastrowIS = passageclientsheet.getLastRow();
  const dataIS = passageclientsheet.getRange(2,1,numlastrowIS,3).getValues();
  var lignes=[]
  dataIS.forEach(function(row,i)
  {
    if (row[0]==NomClient)
    {
      if(row[2]=="non")
      {
        row[2]= "oui"
        lignes.push(i+2)
      }
    }
  });
  passageclientsheet.getRange(2,1,numlastrowIS,3).setValues(dataIS)
  if (lignes.length>0) Browser.msgBox('Ligne(s) modifiée()s : '+lignes.join(','))
}
```

### reference

[setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: this works perfect. 

But I have the following questions : 
1 - why "function(row,i)"? the "i" is for the column?
2- why there is no ";" at the end of these two lignes and it does still works ? (sorry I said I am new at script google sheets).
        row[2]= "oui"
        lignes.push(i+2)
3- why i+2 is used in this ligne
lignes.push(i+2)

Comment: 1/ in `.forEach(function(row,i,j)` i is the row, j is the column, you can omit j and i if not necessary 2/ as datIS begins in row 2 and an array begins by 0, i correct the line i by adding 2